# SQL Insert/update field with text before a character

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and one of my tables, `User_tb`, has a column, `user_email`, where I store users' email addresses. I am relatively new to SQL, but I need to insert `'Sponsored'` before the `@` from the email address.

Example, `dummyuser@gmail.com` => `dummyuserSponsored@gmail.com`

All my research points me to using `substr` however I am not exactly sure how to actually executed on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There should be a replace function in which you could replace @ with Sponsered@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update User_tb set user_email = replace(user_email, '@', 'Sponsored@')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: I would edit this to the person's table: User_tb and column: user_email but otherwise, yes, this is the easiest way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/285be1/3) just because I started doing something you ended up doing anyways and beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you a bunch, it worked like a charm. Looks like I was over complicating it in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

You can do the following:

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET emailColumn = REPLACE (emailColumn, '@', 'Sponsored@')
```

This way you replace any @ symbol with the additional characters that you need. You can test this with the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE (emailcolumn, '@', 'Sponsored@') as emailColumn From MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch, it worked like a charm. Looks like I was over complicating it in my brain.